# Count number of tr with a logic

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to count the number of `tr` where true several conditions.

Input:

```
<table>
  <tr><td>Open   </td><td>Close   </td><td>Price   </td><td>Volume   </td></tr>
  <tr><td>-----</td><td>-----</td><td>-----</td><td>-----</td></tr>
  <tr><td>  3.350</td><td>  3.800</td><td>  3.500</td><td>  0</td></tr>
  <tr><td>  2.750</td><td>  3.400</td><td>  3.500</td><td>  3.500</td></tr>
  <tr><td>  3.550</td><td>  3.200</td><td>  3.500</td><td>  0</td></tr>
  <tr><td>  4.150</td><td>  3.500</td><td>  3.500</td><td>  3.500</td></tr>
</table>
```

The output should be:

```
<fieldSet name="NZXGainers" value="1"/>
<fieldSet name="NZXDecliners" value="1"/>
```

Logic:

- Calculation: Count of all `tr` where `td[4]` ≠ 0, and `td[3]` - `td[1]` > 0 then output `<fieldSet name="NZXGainers" value="{number of tr}"/>`
- Calculation: Count of all `tr` where `td[4]` ≠ 0, and `td[3]` - `td[1]` < 0 then output `<fieldSet name="NZXDecliners" value="{number of tr}"/>`

Comment: So what are you struggling with exactly in terms of XSLT/XPath? To find and use the function named `count`? To use the right XPath syntax for `!=`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can try this**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="table">
        <xsl:for-each select="tr">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="td[4][normalize-space(text()) != '0'] and number(normalize-space(td[3])) - number(normalize-space(td[1])) > 0">
                    <fieldSet name="NZXGainers" value="{count(current())}"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="td[4][normalize-space(text()) != '0'] and number(normalize-space(td[3])) - number(normalize-space(td[1])) &lt; 0">
                    <fieldSet name="NZXDecliners" value="{count(current())}"/>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="table">
    <xsl:element name="fieldSet ">
        <xsl:attribute name="name" select="'NZXGainers'"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="value">
            <xsl:value-of select="count(tr[starts-with(translate(translate(normalize-space(td), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ', ''), '0123456789+-.', '9'), '9')]
              [not(normalize-space(td[4])=0) and (number(normalize-space(td[3])) - number(normalize-space(td[1]))) gt 0])"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>

    <xsl:element name="fieldSet ">
        <xsl:attribute name="name" select="'NZXDecliners'"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="value">
            <xsl:value-of select="count(tr[starts-with(translate(translate(normalize-space(td), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ', ''), '0123456789+-.', '9'), '9')]
              [not(normalize-space(td[4])=0) and (number(normalize-space(td[3])) - number(normalize-space(td[1]))) lt 0])"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Below code to find all rows (tr) having only numerals in their 'td's:

```
tr[starts-with(translate(translate(normalize-space(td), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ', ''), '0123456789+-.', '9'), '9')]
```